# An Alternate Formulation of Rouche's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, rouches-theorem

The general form of [Rouche's Theorem states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem):

> For any two complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$ holomorphic inside
> some region  $K$ with closed contour $\partial K$ if $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$
> on  $\partial K$, then $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeros
> inside  $K$, where each zero is counted as many times as its
> multiplicity. This theorem assumes that the contour $\partial K$ is
> simple, that is, without self-intersections.

Is the following inequality a correct formulation of Rouche's theorem as well?

If $|f + g| < |f| + |g|$ for all $z \in \partial K$, where $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on $K$, then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros inside $K$.

I am trying to prove this statement: $|f + g| < |f| + |g| \Rightarrow $ same number of zeros for $f$ and $g$. But my gut feeling is telling me that it is different from the statement in Rouche's theorem, and it may not be correct to begin with. I have tried to come up with a counter-example, but could not make one that always satisfices the strict inequality.

If it is not correct, please give a small explicit counter-example, and if it is correct please point out why it's true and how can it be shown that it is equivalent to its general form (i.e. the statement from Wikipedia)

**Update**

As discussed in the comment section, this is a valid formulation of Rouche's theorem too. It is called its [symmetric version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version). Can someone please provide a simple, self-contained argument as to why the symmetric version implies the general version? (by general, I mean the quoted format of the theorem from Wikipedia. I am being informal by calling it the general form, but I hope you understand what I mean).

Comment: just look up the symmetric version of Rouche https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version

Comment: I see! Can you please provide a simple argument as to why the symmetric version implies the general form? The article in Wikipedia is skipping over details in my opinion.

Comment: Because you have a homotopy $h_t=tf-(1-t)g, 0 \le t \le 1$ from $f$ to $-g$ which doesn't vanish on the unit circle (by the hypothesis since if $tf(w)=(1-t)g(w)$ then $|(f+g)(w)|=|f(w)|+g(w)|)$, so by the homotopy invariance of the integral $\int h_t'/h_t$ which counts the zeroes of $h_t$ in the unit disc we get that $h_t$ have same number of zeroes in the unit disc